# Subprocess failed in Leiningen REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Sometimes when running statements through `lein repl` I get following errors:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Subprocess failed {:exit-code 137}
        at clojure.core$ex_info.invokeStatic(core.clj:4617)
        at clojure.core$ex_info.invoke(core.clj:4617)
        at leiningen.core.eval$fn__5732.invokeStatic(eval.clj:264)
        at leiningen.core.eval$fn__5732.invoke(eval.clj:260)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:233)
        at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invokeStatic(eval.clj:366)
        at leiningen.core.eval$eval_in_project.invoke(eval.clj:356)
        at leiningen.repl$server$fn__11838.invoke(repl.clj:243)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:646)
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.invokeStatic(core.clj:1881)
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1881)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:156)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic(core.clj:650)
        at clojure.core$bound_fn_STAR_$fn__4671.doInvoke(core.clj:1911)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What does exit code 137 mean?

I am using [vim-fireplace](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fireplace).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit-code above 128 means that the process died because of a received signal (where exitCode = 128 + signalNumber). In this case it was signal 9 (= SIGKILL); maybe sent because your system is running out of memory?

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly the problem.